# Insert UIView at UIButton location in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UItableViewCell with a UIButton in it. What I'm trying to do is insert a UIVew at the location of the button.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake
                         (myButton.frame.origin.x, myButton.frame.origin.y, 220, 110)];
}
```

The view gets put really high when I run it on the simulator.

What I also want is that it should update it's position in landscape mode.

Here's a screenshot in portrait mode:

[image]

In landscape mode:

[image]

I want the UIView to be at the second circled i on the right.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you are getting and what you are expecting. If you cannot add a picture put it flicker or somewhere and post the link here.

Comment: 220, 110 basing on these values your view is 110 in height.  So obviously it is going to look big. I would say put the height something like myButton.frame.size.height or to the height of your table view cell.

Comment: do it in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: remove constraints in interface builder.

Comment: @FawadMasud I need the constraints tho

Comment: @Alex It didn't help

Comment: @Priyatham51 It didn't help. The problem isn't that its too big.

Comment: I cannot tell how you are adding this newly created myView to the contentView of the UITableViewCell  -- [self.contentView addSubview:self.myView]

Answer (score 1):

Add viewDidLayoutSubviews method and relocate your view that would solve your problem when the app change to landscape mode.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
 self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(myButton.frame.origin.x, myButton.frame.origin.y, 220, 110);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but My first question was the uivew is not going at the buttons location.